# PHP websockets - incorrect Sec-WebSocket-Accept

Tags: php, websocket, base64, sha1

I am attempting to create a server application using PHP websockets.
I have written this script to help detail my problem. The correct values here were provided on Mozilla's WebSocket tutorial.

```
<?php
     define('GUID','258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11');
     $hypkey = "dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==";
     $concat = $hypkey . GUID;
     $sha1 = sha1($concat); 
     $base64 = base64_encode($sha1);

     echo $hypkey . "\n" . $concat . "\n" . $sha1 . "\n" . $base64;


    if ($base64 == "s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=")
        echo "all is right";

?>
```

The output of this script is

```
dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11
b37a4f2cc0624f1690f64606cf385945b2bec4ea
ZEdobElITmhiWEJzWlNCdWIyNWpaUT09MjU4RUFGQTUtRTkxNC00N0RBLTk1Q0EtQzVBQjBEQzg1QjEx
```

As you can see, if it were correct the last line would be "all is right", so I am going wrong somewhere. I have reread this part of the tutorial and the Websocket draft several times, and don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it's not explicitly stated in Mozilla's articles on writing a WebSocket server, the `sha1` needs to be the **`raw binary digest`** in order to output the correct value for a websocket handshake.

According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), the `sha1()` function takes the `$str` as the first parameter and a boolean `$raw_output` value as the second, which determines the output type. By default, `$raw_output` is set to `FALSE`, which returns a hexadecimal value.

So to get the correct value in this situation, pass `true` as the second argument to `sha1()`:

`$sha1 = sha1($concat, true);`

Comment: This got the right answer. How was I to know that, after all the documentation I read, it simply said take the sha1 hash... It never said it had to be raw!

Comment: @A.Johnston Yeah, it's definitely not clearly stated anywhere! I actually ended up having to read the Mozilla tutorial on [writing a WebSocket server in Java](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java) to find this code: `.printBase64Binary(
                    MessageDigest
                    .getInstance("SHA-1")
                    .digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
                            .getBytes("UTF-8")))
            + "\r\n\r\n")` which gets the digest.